# An entire function $f$ has a zero at origin of multiplicity $7$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let , $f$ be an entire function such that $f$ has a zero at the origin of multiplicity $7$. Then , which is correct ?

(A) There exists $\delta>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that for $|a|<\epsilon$ , the equation $f(z)=a$ has at least one multiple root in $0<|z|<\delta$.

(B) There exists $\delta>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that for $|a|<\epsilon$ , the equation $f(z)=a$ has $7$ simple roots in $0<|z|<\delta$.

(C) There exists $\delta>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that for $|a|<\epsilon$ , the equation $f(z)=a$ has a root of multiplicity $7$ in $0<|z|<\delta$.

(D) There exists $\delta>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that for $|a|<\epsilon$ , the equation $f(z)=a$ has no root in $0<|z|<\delta$.

I tried through example. Let , $f(z)=z^7$. Then $f$ is entire and has a zero at origin of multiplicity $7$. Then $z^7=a$ has $7$ simple roots. So option (B) is correct. Am I correct ? If I am correct then how I prove this ?

Please help me.

Comment: Well do you know any theorem of complex analysis that tells you anything about roots of functions that are "close" to each other...?

Comment: @@ Najib Idrissi) No .I don't know..Please tell it...I only know the Rouche's theorem about roots

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has merits and issues. Considering $f(z) = z^7$ is a good choice, but it's maybe more useful to disprove statements than it is to prove them since the statements are to be taken as universally true (for functions with a zero of order $7$).

So consider for example (A), which says that $f(z)-a$ has at least a multiple root outside the origin. But you've realized that it has $7$ single roots, and that's it - so (A) is false since $f(z)=z^7$ is a counter example. The same applies to (C) and (D).